# Dataframe write parquet partition folder name

Tags: pyspark, parquet

Suppose I have a dataframe would like to write as partition parquet using year.
So now the folder structure is

```
/parquettable/year=2021/*.parquet
/parquettable/year=2020/*.parquet.......etc.
```

Can I make it `/parquettable/2021/*.parquet`?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you always can rename the folder after you write it, so the answer to your question is **yes**, you can make it `/parquettable/2021/*.parquet`.

But you **shouldn't** do it, because the pattern `year=2021` helps Hive and Spark know what partition (`year`) and which partition (`2021`) are they dealing with. You can read [this link](https://www.datio.com/iaas/understanding-the-data-partitioning-technique/) to see how these partition folders are structured.